# LibGDX: Create new scene2d Object inside another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx, thread-safety, scene2d

I've got a database which stores e.g. the key of an image for a [TextureAtlas](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html). Because the database query shouldn't block the main thread, the query is executed on another thread.

Now I want to create a scene2d actor and return that, so it can be shown.

```
new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String resultOfQuery = ...;
            final Image image = new Image(atlas.findRegion(resultOfQuery));

            Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listener.onImageCreated(image);
                }
            }); 
        }
    }.start();
```

As you can see I'm creating the Image in the new thread and then pass it to the main thread. But the libGDX [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading) states:

> You should never perform multi-threaded operations on anything that is graphics or audio related, e.g. use scene2D components from multiple threads.

Do I have to create **and** assign the actor to the stage on the main thread? Or is it ok, if I create it inside another thread and then add it to the stage on the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only potential issue I see above is calling findRegion on the atlas, which isn't thread safe. But if you know that your thread is not running while the atlas is being used elsewhere it would be ok. If you have multiple queries going on that could all potentially access the atlas, you'd have a problem. Or if you are calling atlas methods in your game loop.

Of course, you could simply use the no-argument Image constructor and pass it a region in the game thread runnable. Then you would have nothing to worry about.

Comment: So what exactly is meant by the sentence in the wiki? What do they mean by saying "never perform multi-threaded operations on [...] scene2d components"?

Comment: Don’t access them from multiple threads concurrently. Since you are not using a background thread to access the Image after you add it to the stage, you are not doing this. You are creating it on one thread and then adding it to your stage in the main game thread. There's never an opportunity for two threads to concurrently access that image.

Comment: But that paragraph in the wiki is misleading because it conflates the fact that LibGDX objects are not thread safe (cannot be safely used from multiple concurrent threads) with the fact that *graphical* objects cannot be used from background threads whatsoever. This is because only the main game thread has access to OpenGL calls. So you cannot instantiate a new Texture or try to draw something with a batch in a background thread

Comment: In your answer above you mentioned that it's possible to use findRegion in another thread as long as the atlas is not used elsewhere. Why is that? I can't see the reason why this would be a problem.

Comment: @Antict Maybe it's OK, maybe it's not. It's not marked as a thread-safe class, so it's safe to say it's not. You could carefully check the source code to see if `findRegion` would have issues in a multi-threaded situation. Depending on how it's implemented, it might. It probably involves iterating an Array, which might cause exceptions if done concurrently by multiple threads. And even if it's safe now, it might be broken in a later version of LibGDX.